# Paginating datatable with unknown record size

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am having some issues for paginating a datatable  with unkown totalRecords with primeng,  i have a complex query and i don't need to know my totals, it's causing a waste of memory for me.
I want to  show only 'First', 'Previous' 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, without showing the number of pages.
How can I paginate with an unkown totalRecords.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="books" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,15,20]"
  totalRecords="unkown" pageLinks="3">
```

Comment: How could logically know how to paginate a `last` request if you don't have a total number of elements?

Comment: We can disable the last button an keep only first, previous, next, is that possible? thanks

Comment: You can try? Set totalRecords to a very high number and disable last with css..

Comment: But "next" button will be displayed even if there is no more data